# can one get back a data that has been deleted from a database? if it is possible how can it be done?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

can one get back a data that has been deleted from a database? if it is possible how can it be done?

Comment: Do u have back ups ?

Comment: without backup its not possible

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: With logging it can be done without a back-up.

Comment: Yep, just use the backup you made.

Comment: @TarangP if db is oracle, it' possible, depending on your retention time parameter and being flashback is on as @ jarlh and @ MT0 told.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan. Thanks

Comment: @TarangP Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle**

If you have not `COMMIT`ted the `DELETE` then you can use `ROLLBACK`.

If you have `COMMIT`ted the `DELETE` and you have [`FLASHBACK`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9012.htm) turned on then you can restore it to a previous point before the `DELETE`.

If neither of those work then you will be relying on backups.